# Sonicwall - SSH to change admin password

Tags: sonicwall, ssh

Is it possible to reset a password for the admin account on a Sonicwall via SSH?

Comment: You should if you have another admin account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a valid configuration backup you can boot sonicwall in safe mode and change admin password, which is **not** stored in exported backup file. 
You have to phisically access the appliace, however...
See https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw8010
So: 
-find configuration backup
-start safe mode in your sonicwall as per kb article
-change password
-reboot appliance in normal mode
-restore configuration

Answer (score 0):

I found a command reference that mentioned the following, but it didn't work on the TZ appliance I had to test on.  It may be NSA only?

`admin-password old-password <WORD> new-password <WORD> confirm-password <WORD>`